# Panache reactiveTransactional timeout with no stack trace

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache, smallrye-reactive-messaging

Hi I have played a lot with the following code and has read https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/21111

I think I am facing a very similar issue, where it will work the first **4 times** and then it stops working and things are stuck and eventually showing.

```
2022-09-15 23:21:21,029 ERROR [io.sma.rea.mes.provider] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-16) SRMSG00201: Error caught while processing a message: io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Timeout
```

I have seen such exact behaviours in multiple bug reports and discussion threads.

I am using quarkus-hibernate-reactive-panache + quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging with kafka (v2.12)

```
@Incoming("words-in")
@ReactiveTransactional
public Uni<Void> storeToDB(Message<String> message) {
    return storeMetamodels(message).onItemOrFailure().invoke((v, throwable) -> {
        if (throwable == null) {
            Log.info("Successfully stored");
            message.ack();
        } else {
            Log.error(throwable, throwable);
            message.nack(throwable);
        }
    });
}

private Uni<Void> storeMetamodels(Message<String> message) {
    List<EntityMetamodel> metamodels = Lists.newArrayList();
        for (String metamodelDsl : metamodelDsls.getMetamodelDsls()) {
            try {
                EntityMetamodel metamodel = new EntityMetamodel();
                metamodel.setJsonSchema("{}") 
                metamodels.add(metamodel);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.error(e, e);
            }

        }

    return Panache.getSession().chain(session -> session.setBatchSize(10)
            .persistAll(metamodels.toArray((Object[]) new EntityMetamodel[metamodels.size()])));
}
```

**NOTE** This same code works if it is running on RestEasy Reactive but I need to move the actual processing and storing to DB away from rest easy as it will be a  large process and I do not want it to be stuck on the Rest API waiting for a few minutes.

Hope some Panache or smallrye reactive messaging experts can shed some lights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this approach, please?

```java
@Inject
Mutiny.SessionFactory sf;

@Incoming("words-in")
public Uni<Void> storeToDB(Message<String> message) {
    return storeMetamodels(message).onItemOrFailure().invoke((v, throwable) -> {
        if (throwable == null) {
            Log.info("Successfully stored");
            message.ack();
        } else {
            Log.error(throwable, throwable);
            message.nack(throwable);
        }
    });
}

private Uni<Void> storeMetamodels(Message<String> message) {
    List<EntityMetamodel> metamodels = Lists.newArrayList();
        for (String metamodelDsl : metamodelDsls.getMetamodelDsls()) {
            try {
                EntityMetamodel metamodel = new EntityMetamodel();
                metamodel.setJsonSchema("{}") 
                metamodels.add(metamodel);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.error(e, e);
            }

        }

    return sf
        .withTransaction( session -> session
            .setBatchSize(10)
            .persistAll(metamodels.toArray((Object[]) new EntityMetamodel[metamodels.size()]))
        );
}
```

I suspect you've hit a bug where the session doesn't get closed at the end of `storeToDB`. Because the session doesn't get closed when injected using Panache or dependency injection, the connection stays open and you hit the limit of connections that can stay open.

At the moment, using the session factory makes it easier to figure out when the session gets closed.

Comment: Hi Davide, I actually tried that approach before and again now that you suggested and it is still the same problem. It is rather hard to even try to find where the issue is as there is no stack trace. It definitely failed as I see this in the logs 08:37:06,313 ERROR [com.sim.MyReactiveMessagingApplication] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-22) io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Timeout: io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Timeout

08:37:06,314 ERROR [io.sma.rea.mes.kafka] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-22) SRMSG18203: A message sent to channel `words-in` has been nacked, fail-stop

Comment: sorry, it works now, I forgot to remove ReactiveTransactional.

Comment: Nice. I hear you. We are aware of this issue and we are working on fixing it and make everything more user friendly.

Comment: Thanks Davide for the help. I have been fighting with it for two sleepless nights. I definitely have tried multiple ways and I guess I got lost  and forget to remove annotations with all the back and forth. Your solution made me double checked my annotations.